# Docker Machine/Swarm with Consul -- secure by default?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I've used the commands from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jacobmarshall/77d6b3ba7c6c50de22eb) (duplicated below) to create a Docker Swarm using Consul.

```
docker-machine create \
  --driver=digitalocean \
  --digitalocean-access-token=$DO_TOKEN \
  --digitalocean-size=512mb \
  --digitalocean-region=nyc3 \
  --digitalocean-private-networking=true \
  --digitalocean-image=ubuntu-15-04-x64 \
    docker-swarm-kv-store

docker $(docker-machine config docker-swarm-kv-store) run -d \
  --net=host progrium/consul --server -bootstrap-expect 1

kvip=$(docker-machine ip docker-swarm-kv-store)

docker-machine create \
  --driver=digitalocean \
  --digitalocean-access-token=$DO_TOKEN \
  --digitalocean-size=2gb \
  --digitalocean-region=nyc3 \
  --digitalocean-private-networking=true \
  --digitalocean-image=ubuntu-15-04-x64 \
  --swarm \
  --swarm-master \
  --swarm-discovery consul://${kvip}:8500 \
  --engine-opt "cluster-store consul://${kvip}:8500" \
  --engine-opt "cluster-advertise eth1:2376" \
    docker-swarm-master

docker-machine create \
  --driver=digitalocean \
  --digitalocean-access-token=$DO_TOKEN \
  --digitalocean-size=2gb \
  --digitalocean-region=nyc3 \
  --digitalocean-private-networking=true \
  --digitalocean-image=ubuntu-15-04-x64 \
  --swarm \
  --swarm-discovery consul://${kvip}:8500 \
  --engine-opt "cluster-store consul://${kvip}:8500" \
  --engine-opt "cluster-advertise eth1:2376" \
    docker-swarm-agent-1

eval $(docker-machine env --swarm docker-swarm-master)
docker info
```

Does Docker Machine ensure that the swarm is secure (perhaps by managing SSL certs under-the-covers), or can anyone join my Consul cluster by pointing at `${kvip}:8500`?

Comment: Downvoting without comment isn't helpful; please leave a comment as to how I can improve the question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the answer is that **the cluster isn't secured by default**.

The second command listed above is where the Consul service is started. If certs were getting passed in, they'd show up in that line.

The [Consul Getting Started guide](https://www.consul.io/intro/getting-started/join.html) requires only the hostname/port of another node in the cluster you wish to join -- no authentication needed. However, if you've generated TLS certs, you can add them [as shown in the DigitalOcean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-consul-with-tls-encryption-on-ubuntu-14-04#move-the-files-to-the-correct-location). One caveat is that since the original question mentions running Consul within a Docker container, you'll need to use volumes to move the certificates in.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @RyanKennedy mentions, consider too that anyone can:

- join an agent to the consul cluster (one way to avoid this might to be use [encryption](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html#_encrypt))
- submit data to consul (which you could avoid by using [ACL tokens](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html#acl_token))

Obviously, this all assumes that nothing else is providing protection, but to provide some depth to your defenses, I would definitely consider the two config items mentioned above.